# writerow in Python 3 writes me always a blank line beetween the origin lines, Python2 works great. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have trouble with my Code. in Python2 I use withopen to print something in a csv, it works great. When i Use Python 3 i have to remove the BinaryMode (wb) an then it always print a blank line beetween the correct lines. Why ?

```
with open('C:\\Users\\KDD1SGM\\Desktop\\example\\exportPython3.csv', mode="wb") as out: 
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerow(writeData)
    for i in range(len(newfunctions)):
        writer.writerow(newfunctions[i])
```

and the output is as follows:

> line1: 1,2,3
>
> line2: 4,5,6
>
> ....

when i try to remove the Binary Mode in with open (for Python3) the output csv is:

> line1: 1,2,3
>
> line2: 4,5,6
>
> line3: ...

why is there a blank line now ? and how to remove it ?

Comment: inside open do this : newline='' like : with open('C:\\Users\\KDD1SGM\\Desktop\\example\\exportPython3.csv', mode="wb", newline='')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2, if you open `out` with mode `'wb'` then `csv.writer` writes `\r\n` into the file directly. It will write `\r\r\n` only if you open it in binary mode, because on Windows it will translate each `\n` into `\r\n`.

In Python 3 fortunately the syntax changed, so open `out` with the additional parameter `newline=''` instead to avoid any hassle.

#### Example:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\KDD1SGM\\Desktop\\example\\exportPython3.csv', mode="w", newline='') as out: 
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerow(writeData)
    for i in range(len(newfunctions)):
        writer.writerow(newfunctions[i])
```

#### Sources

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation! have a nice day Alex